# Test case for File polling using cron expression

Tags: spring-integration

how to create test case for file polling using cron expression ?
i am using file processing using cron poller but when i create test case it fails .
Messages from queue is null so we are getting null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to start from the [Sample Application](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/file):

Comment: when i use fixeddelay in poller then it works but if i change it to cron expression .it gives me null in test case

Comment: is there any sample which implements cron expression for polling and test as well

Comment: Well, then you don't wait enough time for cron action. You have to share your configuration and test-case to play from our side.